# Overiding layoutSubviews in custom UITableViewCell superclass

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios-autolayout

`CustomUITableViewChildCell` is a subclass of `CustomUITableViewParentCell` - both contain the same subview properties. However, they are laid-out different auto-layout constraints. Both override `layoutSubviews`. But I don't want the child class to call `super layoutSubviews` and thus get constraints from the parent class. (I still need to call it otherwise the controller doesn't draw the separator lines. How do I remove the constraints from `CustomUITableViewParentCell` but not from the UIKit grandparent classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by manually removing the affected subviews in `layoutSubviews` of the subclass, then re-adding them. By removing them from the table view cell, they had the constraints from the superclass removed, and so I was able to apply new ones afterwards.